# What software for Mac OS X can take auto screen captures at intervals?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, screenshot, screen-capture

I need a piece of software for Mac OS X 10.6 similar to [AutoScreenShot](http://www.theuds.com/autoscreenshot.php?lang=EN) for Windows that will take screenshots at intervals for me.

I'm trying to make a time-lapsed video of my work on an illustration, except it's going to be about a 5 - 10 hour illustration so I don't want to use any video capture software. I'm specifically looking for something that will do automatic screen shots. The software mentioned above would be perfect except it is only for Windows.

I have already checked out several podcasting applications, screencasting applications and even screencapture applications but none seem to have this automated function I'm looking for. I've checked out:

- Jing
- CaptureMe
- Copernicus
- Quicktime
- Podcast Capture (built into Mac OS X)
- DVD Snap (which would be perfect except it only runs through Apple's DVD Player)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The quick'n'dirty way: [set up a timed Terminal command](http://www.trickyways.com/2010/01/how-to-set-timer-to-take-screenshot-on-mac-using-terminal/).

Comment: Ooooo - hard core. If I hadn't found my software for this, I would have opted for this option. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I found a great freeware program called [InstantShot!](http://projects.digitalwaters.net/instantshot.html) and have been using it now for the afternoon. It works really well, and you can set it up for auto shots that go right into whatever folder you want them to, at any second intervals you'd like. It's really convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The donationware [Timed Screenshot](http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/Freeware/TimedScreenshot.shtml) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

CaptureMe suppports AppleScript, so you might be able to do it by [using AppleScript](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20030115080027106).

I did not use Google to see if any of the others support AppleScript, after I found that CaptureMe did, so you might want to check if the others do too.